# send a sms without any gateway using jsp/servlet

Tags: jsp, networking, servlets, mobile, sms

I want to build an Web-application using jsp/servlets where we will be able to send sms to recipient,lwt me know,wheather could it be possible without using gateway/gsm modem or I must have to use that.I don't want to use 3rd party's sms appliation.

Comment: You mean like WhatsApp messing system?

Comment: i want send a text sms to mobile phone using jsp/servlet without any gateway?

Comment: you can do it using a modem/mobile device in the server and use that mobile to send SMS. Certainly there is no way to send SMS for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a 3rd parties gateway into top level aggregators for this or get a gateway into them yourself (can have expensive setup fee's). (I work in this field).

Comment: Thanks for reply,but I don't want to use any 3rd party's /any gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used http://www.smspm.com/en and I am very happy with it. Simple, easy and they have an API for it as well.

Comment: They have manual which can be downloaded from http://www.smspm.com/en/SMS-Gateway-API the sample code is in PHP but you can implement in JSP as it is just a URL that you need to generate. Easy stuff

Comment: The line which is $answer = file_get_contents("http://.... should be changed to JSP instead of PHP. This should help you http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/ReadFromURL.html?l=rel

Comment: I write this your according but not integrate in jsp page?

Comment: First you have to create your account and they will provide you with the key than use that key in the URL as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SS7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signaling_System_7) protocol, via ss7 you can send sms/mms messages directly

Comment: how to implement SS7 protocol in jsp/servlet.any you provide the solution?

Comment: start up your investigation from official documentation of the protocol http://www.ncs.gov/library/tech_bulletins/2003/tib_03-2.pdf

Comment: This pdf gives information about the network history not a implementation ss7 and java?

Comment: @swordholder - unless he plans to also build the rest of the MPLN this is not very helpful - and ofcourse, then there is all the peering arrangement with existing operators, etc - not sure how this is helpful to this use case.